# Как удалить блоки в определенном порядке?

Tags: javascript

На странице есть много однотипных блоков.
Пример:

```
arr = document.body.getElementsByClassName('box')
[<div class=​"box" style=​"background-color:​ rgb(122, 233, 132)​;​">​</div>​,
 <div class=​"box" style=​"background-color:​ rgb(133, 154, 188)​;​">​</div>​,
 <div class=​"box" style=​"background-color:​ rgb(59, 243, 75)​;​">​</div>​,
 <div class=​"box" style=​"background-color:​ rgb(175, 245, 235)​;​">​</div>​,
 <div class=​"box" style=​"background-color:​ rgb(56, 211, 118)​;​">​</div>​, и т.д.]
```

По элементу массива мы можем получить определенный блок:

> arr[i]

Меня интересует, как удалить все эти блоки из разметки постепенно, начиная с последнего? В общем, как просто удалить блок по идентификатору?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью селектора `:last-child` можно получить последний блок с выбранным вами классом. Вот так это будет выглядеть в виде кода:

```
var lastBox = document.querySelector('.box:last-child');
```

Чтобы последовательно удалять элементы с конца массива, можно использовать такой код:

```
for (var i = (arr.length - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
  yourRemoveFunction(arr[i]);
}
```

С помощью селектора `:nth-child(n)` можно получить блок с выбранным вами индексом. Вот так это будет выглядеть в виде кода:

```
var selectedBox = document.querySelector('.box:nth-child(5)'); // 5-ый элемент
```

Comment: тоитсь удалить последний тег с данным классом можно так

`for (var i = (arr.length - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
      document.body.removeChild('.box:nth-child(i)')
}`

Comment: @V.Rotenberh, так вы удалите все блоки, начиная с последнего

Comment: спасибо. по сути в этом задача то и была.